# FFT issue in java using Wav files

Tags: java, fft, wav

The application that I’m developing is an application that takes in a “.Wav”(44000Hz file of 15 Sec) sound file of a bird and identifying the bird. So now what I’m doing is that I’m reading the wav file data chunk data and sending them through a FFT. Then from the output of the FFT I get the Amplitudes of the sound file. Then I get the maximum frequency collection which is related with the highest Amplitudes. I take these frequencies to be the unique identification of the particular bird. 
The issue is that, I’m having trouble getting the highest amplitudes for the sound file from the FFT.

Q1. Do I have to send all the sample data as segments through the FFT?

Q2. Is this unique identification method valid?

Comment: For Q2, the only way you'll know is by trying.  You mean you want to differentiate between some individual birds, or between species?  Either way, this seems like a hard AI problem.

Comment: for a species. Do i have to send all the data from the data chunk through the FFT?

Comment: A quick search gives: http://www.springerlink.com/content/u62328343pnu76wj/ and http://www.springerlink.com/content/v5t480022367312q/

Comment: As the links indicate, you'll have to split the sound sample in "syllables".

Comment: thanks for the links and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If the bird modulates their song, sings some sort of melody, you may want to try some form of sound or [accoustic fingerprint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint) (you can google that term).  Take short overlapping time fragments, much less than 1 second long, and FFT each of those.  This will give you a 2 dimensional spectrogram chart which you can try to pattern match against your reference templates.

Comment: thanks. Does this mean that i have to clear the signal (Noise and Silence) in someway before generating the "accoustic fingerprint".

Comment: can someone plz tell me whether i have to clear the signal before applying the accoustic fingerprint?

Comment: Sounds like another question which requires you to provide more detail.

Comment: My sound clip contains noise as well as silence. So do i have to avoid those sample values before applying any calculations like FFT.